# list files under certain directory in a commit

Tags: git, shell

I'm writing a script to retrieve files from a commit under  myDir directory but i can't get it to work here's the script :

```
echo "************* $commit ******************      "
        list_files = `git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $commit | grep myDir`
        for file in $list_files
            do
                echo "File name is : $file "
        done
```

I always get an error in list_files saying that :

> list_files: command not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space before and after =

```
list_files = `git diff-tree
```

should be

```
list_files=`git diff-tree.....`
```

Say, if `x=10` is given as `x = 10`, then shell will think `x` is a command called with 2 arguments. Since there is no such command called `x`, it gives the error command not found.

Comment: could've spent all my life and i would never notice that :p

Answer (score 1):

When using your command (`diff-tree`) while `HEAD` was a commit that had `d/a` and `d/b` to list the contents of `d` in a commit that has `d/a`, `d/b`, and `d/c`, your command only gave me `d/c`. In other words, it listed the files that are not in `HEAD`'s version of the directory.

To answer your title question, this command lists the files in a given commit:

```
git ls-tree -r --name-only "$commit" "$directory"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is too complicated.  Try

```
git ls-files $commit myDir | while read f; do
  echo "file name is $f"
done
```

The improvements are:

- A simpler Git command specifically invented to list files in the specified commit under the specified prefix.
- You process the files output by that command as it outputs them —
  instead of saving all the output into a giant string and then splitting it again.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. The manpage of `ls-files` says it only works with files in the index and working tree. It doesn't take a commit argument.